# With xlink:title deprecated what's the proper way to add a title to an SVG?

Tags: svg

With [xlink:title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:title) deprecated. New content should use a  child element rather than a xlink:title attribute. But how exactly?  An example would be great. This is my code.

```
<svg class="icon"><use href="#comment-solid"></use></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon">
  <title>This is the title for the SVG element</title>

  <defs>
    <circle id="comment-solid" r="100" />
  </defs>
  
  <use href="#comment-solid">
    <title>This is the title for the "use" element</title>
  </use>
</svg>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title